# Ajax Send Post Data with Graphic Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The graphic button below has no value, just an id. I am trying to bring some results from the database when I click on it. I have to get results according to the *span* inside the graphic button structure.

```
<a class="uib-graphic-button default-graphic-sizing default-image-sizing hover-graphic-button active-graphic-button default-graphic-button default-graphic-text widget uib_w_10 d-margins media-button-text-bottom" data-uib="media/graphic_button" data-ver="0" id="admin">
    <img src="images/administrativa.png">
    <span class="uib-caption">Admin</span>
</a>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#admin", function(evt)
{
    /* your code goes here */

    var dataString = "admin=";
    var $server = "http://localhost/project";

    function SelectAdm(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: $server+"/select.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result, jqXHR){

                var vaga = $.parseJSON(result);

                $.each(vaga, function(index, item){
                    var list_item = '<li class="widget uib_w_17" data-uib="jquery_mobile/listitem" data-ver="0" data-icon="carat-r" id="listitem"><a href="#"><span>'+item.CARGO+'</span></a>';

                    $("#list").append(list_item);
                    activate_page("#listpage");

                });

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status){
                alert("not working");
            }
        });
    }
    new SelectAdm();
});
```

php file

```
<?php 

include_once("conn.php");

if(isset($_POST['admin'])){

$adm = "administrativa";

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM vagas WHERE area = '".$adm."' ");

if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH)){
        $registro = array(
            "AREA" => $row['area'],
            "CARGO" => $row['cargo'],
            "ATIVIDADES" => $row['atividades'],
            "SALARIO_INI" => $row['salario_ini'],
            "POS_EXPERIENCIA" => $row['pos_experiencia'],
            "BENEFICIOS" => $row['beneficios'],
            "HORARIO" => $row['horario'],
            "ESCOLARIDADE" => $row['escolaridade'],
            "LOCAL" => $row['local'],
            "INFOS_ADICIONAIS" => $row['infos_adicionais']                      
        );

        $retorno[] = $registro;

    }       
}

$mysqli->close();
$retorno = json_encode($retorno);
echo $retorno;

}

?>
```

Am I sending it wrong? When I work with inputs it all works fine, mounting the data like this:

```
var state = $("#state").val(); 
var city =$("#city").val();
var dataString = "state="+state+"&city="+city+"&submit=";
```

How does it work without inputs?

Comment: You don't need inputs to perform an Ajax call... Please describe the problem or error you're having or post a link where we can test it. Just a few comments: It's a link, not a _graphical button_. Bind the event to the parent or to `$("body")` instead to `$(document)` and there is no need for a function nor to instantiate it inside the event handler, remove the function and the `new SelectAdm()` and just make the Ajax call.

Comment: @Gabriel all this code is from the inside of intel xdk, an hybrid app and it works on another app. Just this one is returning nothing from the query. One error I´ve got when I made some changes on php file was "Unexpected end of input"

Comment: In PHP, that basically means that you left a bracket or something unclosed. In JS that means that the response is not valid and cannot be parsed. Aside, you should get rid of `var vaga = $.parseJSON(result);` because jQuery parses JSON automatically.

Comment: My PHP is perfect. It was some issues on my database table like accents. I removed them and it worked. parseJSON is really needed in XDK. Thanks anyway.